# How to change column count in listing page Magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to make product listing page to use 3 columns instead of 4 default columns.

I've got some categories on my Magento2 Web, and some products on each category. I want them to show as 3 columns count, but it always shows as 4 default columns count, how can i change plz help me for this.

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 don't have an option to set a column count as Magento 1.

To change from 4 to 3 (for theme based on Luma) you will need to change CSS and to reset image size.

CSS code that you need to change is inside Magento_Catalog module, file:

```
_listings.less
```

and it is like this:

```
    .media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
  .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
  .page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/6 }
  .page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/4 }
  .page-products .products-grid .product-items { margin: 0; }
  .page-products .products-grid .product-item {
    width: 24.439%;
    margin-left: calc(~"(100% - 4 * 32.439%) / 3");
    padding: 0;
    &:nth-child(3n+1) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .page-products.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
  .page-products.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/4 }
}
```

to have 3 columns, change it to (I recommend add this code to _theme.less):

```
    .media-width(@extremum, @break) when (@extremum = 'min') and (@break = @screen__l) {
  .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/4 }
  .page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/5 }
  .page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
  .page-products .products-grid .product-items { margin: 0; }
  .page-products .products-grid .product-item {
    width: 32.439%;
    margin-left: calc(~"(100% - 3 * 32.439%) / 2");
    padding: 0;
    &:nth-child(3n+1) {
      margin-left: 0;
    }
  }
  .page-products.page-layout-1column .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/4 }
  .page-products.page-layout-3columns .products-grid .product-item { width: 100%/3 }
}
```

after this in

/your_theme/etc/view.xml

change small image width and height. Now is 240 and 300, change it to something like 300 and 330.

Refresh and that is it.